# Is there a way for sprites to recognise colours with SKPhysicsBody

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am making a game that involves moving a sprite with your finger and has to avoid procedurally generated sprites for 1 1/2 minutes. The obstacles would have taken a long time to program considering I will be making ~25 levels, so instead, I used the SKScene animator to create the obstacles to move across the screen. Each obstacle is only one colour,r and every obstacle is the same colour. So is there a piece of code that I can apply in the override function 'update' can continously check if the player sprite is overlapping a specific colour?

Comment: You have 32 flags (categorybitmask) you can use to determine what type of collision happens

Comment: So, I need to name all the obstacles, give them all the same bitMask and make a function to check is the player is overlapping a sprite with that bitMask?